# Where does reducer resides in Cluster?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new in HADOOP. Have some basic queries.

1. Where does reduces resides in Cluster. I mean Is there any specific 
    datanode for this purpose.(If yes then how it is decided)
2. Where does shuffling,sorting,combining & partition occurs.

Your help will be highly useful.

Comment: Have you read about the concept of data locality? What resource are you using to learn Hadoop. These questions should be answered there,

Comment: @cricket_007 : I am learning on my own with different resources. Haven't heard about data locality. Can you help ?

Comment: I can refer you to get a copy of "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide", but I trust your ability to search for the phrase I just said.